# Back button gets stuck in a loop after submitting a new comment

Tags: 7, comments

I have a comment form shown below the comments list on a node page. I'm using pathauto for urls.

When I visit the page with the my-node-page#new link and then submit a comment it loads the node with a my-node-page#comment-1234. When I click the back button to get to the previous page I get to my-node-page#new. I click back again and get to my-node-page#comment-1234 and so on ...

I'll probably use [Ajax Comments](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) soon to avoid the page reload. Any ideas what I can do in the meantime? Looks like a bug in Drupal to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up fixing it by using [Ajax comments](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments)